# Security permissions appearing as long numbers instead of user name

Tags: permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I transferred over folders/files from one server to another using robocopy for Server 2003. However, for each individual that has special permissions to access a folder or file the security permissions show them as a long number instead of a user name like say, Bob.Smith.

Is there a way to copy the permissions over so that they appear normally and coincide with users of this new server? Users on both servers are the same, this is a server upgrade.

Comment: Are they local users or domain users?

Comment: The users are not the same. The user names may be the same but the user entities are actually different. What you're seeing is the SID (security identifier) for the user on the old server, which doesn't coincide with the users on the new server.

Comment: Great. Is there a way that I can make an exact copy of the users from the old server to the new server and maintaining the same SID? Linking them wouldn't work since eventually the old server will be decommissioned.